# How to define preprocessor macro to check iOS version

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, c-preprocessor

I use it to check iOS version, but it doesn't work:

```
#ifndef kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_5_0
#define kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_5_0 675.000000
#endif

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= __IPHONE_5_0
#define IF_IOS5_OR_GREATER(...) \
if (kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber >= kCFCoreFoundationVersionNumber_iPhoneOS_5_0) \
{ \
__VA_ARGS__ \
}
#else
#define IF_IOS5_OR_GREATER 0
#endif
```

when I make

```
#if IF_IOS5_OR_GREATER
NSLog(@"iOS5");
#endif
```

nothing happens. Is something wrong here?

Comment: Do you want this to check whether a user of your app is running iOS 5? If so, you want something like James' method. A preprocessor macro won't help you with that, as it runs at compile-time.

Comment: There are no runtime checks in your code, so how on earth is it supposed to know the current iOS version? All you are doing is checking the version of the SDK that your code was compiled with.

Comment: Err @MikeWeller (and Chris), I'm afraid neither of you are correct. The macro indeed does create a runtime check if the compile time conditional is met. The OP was simply calling the macro incorrectly. See here for a full explanation of how this works: http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/07/tips-tricks-for-conditional-ios3-ios32.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've defined a macro, but you're using it in the non-macro way. Try something like this, with your same macro definition.

```
IF_IOS5_OR_GREATER(NSLog(@"iOS5");)
```

(This is instead of your `#if`/`#endif` block.)

Comment: Is there something you could help me out : http://stackoverflow.com/q/21275316/434898. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Much simpler:

```
#define IS_IOS6_AND_UP ([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue] >= 6.0)
```

Comment: This has the drawback that you can't use it outside of code blocks, for example in header files, etc.

Answer (score 10):

```objc
#ifdef __IPHONE_5_0
```

etc

Just look for that constant. All the objective c constants start with two underscores

Comment: This is a preprocessor macro, meaning it's executed when the app is being compiled, rather than on the user's device. Also, a correct answer was already selected nearly a year ago...

Comment: This macro is useful to separate the code in compiling time with `#ifdef` and `#ifndef`, all the other answers are only available in the runtime with `if` statement usage.

Answer (score 5):

Define this method:

```
+(BOOL)iOS_5 {
    NSString *osVersion = @"5.0";
    NSString *currOsVersion = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
    return [currOsVersion compare:osVersion options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending;
}
```

Then define the macro as that method.

Comment: NSOrderedAscending will make this method return false if the current os is >= 5.0. You should use NSOrderedDescending

Answer (score 2):

For a runtime check use something like this:

```
- (BOOL)iOSVersionIsAtLeast:(NSString*)version {
    NSComparisonResult result = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:version options:NSNumericSearch];
    return (result == NSOrderedDescending || result == NSOrderedSame);
}
```

If you create a category on UIDevice for it, you can use it as such:

```
@implementation UIDevice (OSVersion)
- (BOOL)iOSVersionIsAtLeast:(NSString*)version {
    NSComparisonResult result = [[self systemVersion] compare:version options:NSNumericSearch];
    return (result == NSOrderedDescending || result == NSOrderedSame);
}
@end
```

...

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice] iOSVersionIsAtLeast:@"6.0"]) self.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#define isIOS7 ([[[UIDevice currentDevice]systemVersion]floatValue] > 6.9) ?1 :0
```