# Dynamic assigning of value to macro function .pch file and checking condition .pch file

Tags: macros, ios7, xcode5, remote-debugging, nslog

.pch as its name shows pre-compiler header, I have defined a macro in the file so that app can decide in the very beginning of the app compilation.

What I need is, possible to load any macro by assigning the values dynamically something like `NSUserDefaults` and checking the condition in `.pch` file itself.

If user disable logs from screen (switch), there should be no logs, else it can print logs, least bother about Debug/Release mode.

I have `" #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " FORMAT), PRETTY_FUNCTION, LINE, ##__VA_ARGS__) "` into my .pch file.

I am looking something like this :

```
#if REMOTEDEBUG_ENABLED   // CHECK FOR NSUserDefaults values and comparing for logs
" #define NSLog(FORMAT, ...) TFLog((@"%s [Line %d] " FORMAT), PRETTY_FUNCTION, LINE, ##__VA_ARGS__) "
#endif
```

Here is the [reference link](http://innovaptor.com/blog/2013/09/02/xcode-preprocessor-macros-for-test-code.html), but that assigning the value to macro from the project settings so didn't worked in my case.

I need to check the condition based on NSUserDefaults. How can I achieve this or any alternative where the app can decide either to print the logs/not using the macro.